# How to print 1st reminder, 2nd reminder in Yii2 GridView from model?

Tags: php, mysql, gridview, yii2

Here is my view page `view.php`

```
<div class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap">
    <?= GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
         'columns' => [
              ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],            
              [
                  'label' =>'Date',
                  'value' => 'date',
              ],
              [
                  'label' =>'Reminder',
                  'value' => function($model){
                       return Yii::$app->session->get('').' '.$model['type'].' '.'reminder';
                  }  
              ],
              [
                  'label' =>'To',
                  'value' => 'recipients',
              ],                    
         ]
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

This is controller

```
$dataProvider1 = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => DomainReminders::find()
                 ->where(['domain_id'=>$model['id']])
]);
$totalCount = $dataProvider1->getTotalCount();

return $this->renderAjax('view', [
   'totalCount' => $totalCount, 
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 
   'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1, 
   true, 
   true
);
```

This is database with column name 'type' I want print like **1st reminder, 2nd reminder, 3rd reminder** in grid view

[image]

Now here is my output i want print like **1st, 2nd reminder**

[image]

Comment: You mean `ORDER BY` the reminder column?

Comment: no above table is view table.in databse have 'type' column i want to print like 1st reminder in REMINDER COLUMN TABLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`Inflector::ordinalize()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseinflector#ordinalize()-detail) for this:

```
[
    'label' => 'Reminder',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return Inflector::ordinalize($model['type']) . ' reminder';
    },
],
```